# Excel VBA: Iterating over Multiple Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently writing a code that automates goalseek but I ran into syntax issues.

I declared 3 variables:

```
Dim X as Range
Dim Y as Range
Dim Z as Range

Set X as Range(....)
Set Y as Range(....)
Set Z as Range(....)

For each cell in X,Y,Z
X.GoalSeek Goal:=Y, ChangingCell:=Z
Next cell in X,Y,Z
```

This is pseudo code but I want it to iterate one by one in each of the cells in range X,Y,Z.

These are column ranges.

Question: How do I have each cell in range X,Y,Z iterate to put into the goalseek function? So if each of the ranges had 5 cells, it would run 5 times.

Comment: There is probably a question (someone) hidden within. Can you help me find it so we can answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `For ... Each` doesn't allow comma seperated arguments after `in`, so you must present "one" range to it ...
2. if you want to say `For Each cell ...` then you must decompose ranges into cells using their `.Cells` property
3. inside the `For ... Each` you then ought to work with the loop variable (`cell`) instead `X`, `Y`, `Z`

Example

```
Sub Test()
Dim X As Range, Y As Range, Z As Range
Dim C As Range

    Set X = [A1]
    Set Y = [B1:B2]
    Set Z = [C1:C3]

    For Each C In Union(X.Cells, Y.Cells, Z.Cells)
        MsgBox C.AddressLocal
    Next C
End Sub
```

Alternative syntax for the `Union(...)` would be

```
For Each C In Union(X, Y, Z).Cells
```

which probably makes it even clearer that you're tieing together 3 ranges and then address each of their cells ... matter of taste maybe

**EDIT**
 under the assumption you want to form TRIPLES of your (equal sized) ranges and feed them into a single function, calculate offsets for ranges Y and Z onto X

example

```
Sub Test()
Dim X As Range, Y As Range, Z As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim OYR As Long, OYC As Long, OZR As Long, OZC As Long

    Set X = [A1:A5]
    Set Y = [B3]        'no need to provide full range, starting point will do
    Set Z = [C5]

    ' calculating offsets
    OYR = Y(1, 1).Row - X(1, 1).Row + 1
    OYC = Y(1, 1).Column - X(1, 1).Column + 1

    OZR = Z(1, 1).Row - X(1, 1).Row + 1
    OZC = Z(1, 1).Column - X(1, 1).Column + 1

    ' iterate thru all cells of X and their equally ofsett partners in Y and Z
    For Each C In X.Cells
        MsgBox C.AddressLocal & " " & C(OYR, OYC).AddressLocal & " " & C(OZR, OZC).AddressLocal
    Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: So let's say I want X + Y = Z with X = [A1:A5] Y = [B1:B5] Z = [C1:C5] the union operator allows me to create a union range [A1:C1] like this? How do I input the position of each cell in that range so it can be used in the goalseek formula?

Comment: your question was to iterate thru all cells of 3 different ranges ... within the loop each cell of all 3 ranges "appear" as C ... so if you want to call a function `GoalSeek` for each of these cells you just replace `MsgBox ...` by `GoalSeek C`

Comment: AAHH ... was your question to form TRIPLES (A,B,C) for equal sized ranges and supply these TRIPLES to a function?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was typing so much that I forgot to ask the question. The offset method is great. Thanks!